# PowerShell silent installation not working for SQL Server 2014

Tags: sql-server, powershell

For silent installation of service pack for SQL Server 2008 or SQL Server 2008 R2, the following command works perfectly fine:

```
powershell.exe -executionpolicy bypass -noninteractive -nologo 
     -file \\ns-sisci01\ServiceOperationsAutomation\BAO-shared\Dev\Programs\MSSQL\SPUpgrade\SP_Installation.ps1  
     USCKU1METY0014\sql2014 d:\sysdba\SQLServer2014SP2-KB3171021-x64-ENU.exe
```

It doesn't prompt me for anything, it simply runs.

When I am using it for SQL Server 2014, it prompts whether I want to run setup
like this

[image]

When I say cancel, it fails and yes it continues.

But this command I am using in some script where I don't want to give any input.

Can you please help if I am missing any parameters?

Comment: means, there r 2 prompts one is above picture and other it ask you are changing something on HD do you want to continue. I want to pass both prompts

Comment: first one gone by right click on properties and unblocking it, wht about second

Comment: Run your command window elevated, then run the command.

Comment: How any example plz or any reference of page

Answer (score -1):

from the description i think it is UAC that is blocking it.

try Disabling UAC, but that would require a reboot.

Disabling UAC, would have security concerns as well,it is used to increase the security of the operating system that can help prevent unauthorized changes to your computer.

[image]

Regards,

Comment: why -negative, neways disabling UAC i need to bypass at runtime because i dont know which server this query is going to execute

Comment: It is not recommended to disable UAC.